# measure theory problem

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I am stuck at **part d)** of this problem.

[image: pic]

Do you see how to show that f is measurable? I must show that $f^{-1}[-\infty,r)$ is measurable for all r. I am not sure how to do it.

I would assume that it is integrable over the given interval? Since the function is measurable its integral is defined. And since the function is bounded, and the interval we integrate over is bounded, the integral must be bounded?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to express the given function as a sum (or limit if you prefer) of functions that are known to be measurable.

For example, if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint measurable sets, $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in A$, and $f(x) = 2$ for all $x \in B$, then you can write $f(x) = 1 \cdot \chi_A(x) + 2 \cdot \chi_B(x)$ which is the sum of two measurable indicator functions.

In your example, the sets $A$, $\mathbb Q \cap (U_n \setminus U_{n+1})$, $\mathbb Q^c \cap (U_n \setminus U_{n+1})$ are pairwise disjoint. Thus you have $$f(x) = 0 \cdot \chi_A(x) + \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{1}{n+1} \cdot \chi_{\mathbb Q \cap (U_n \setminus U_{n+1})}(x) + \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{-1}{n+1} \cdot \chi_{\mathbb Q^c \cap (U_n \setminus U_{n+1})}(x)$$ so that $f$ is a countable sum of measurable functions.